# ¿Era el verbo "solver" regular o irregular?

Tags: verbos, conjugación, arcaísmos

El verbo *solver* se llegó a usar en España con el mismo significado que *resolver*:

> **[solver](https://dle.rae.es/?id=YJmavLR)**
>
> Del lat. *solvĕre*.
>
> 1. tr. desus. Resolver una duda.
> 2. tr. desus. Hallar la solución de un problema.

Lo único es que este verbo ya estaba en desuso en la época del *Diccionario de autoridades*. Y como tal, en el DLE no aparece la conjugación del mismo. Tampoco indica siquiera si su conjugación sigue algún modelo concreto. Así pues, pregunto: ¿era regular el verbo *solver*, siguiendo las formas latinas del verbo (*solvo*) y de forma similar a *[sorber](https://dle.rae.es/?id=YPPEwxg)* (*sorbo*), o seguía el mismo modelo que *[resolver](https://dle.rae.es/?id=WBV06OC)* (*suelvo*)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Era irregular y seguía el mismo patrón que *resolver*. El CORDE nos da algunos (aunque pocos) ejemplos de su uso:

> *E si bien lo consideráredes, está meior ansí, por cuanto en estas palabras se descubren mayores secretos e se suelven más fuertes dudas que si el sol en logar de la luna fuera memorado.*
>
> Enrique de Villena, "Exposición del Salmo 'Quoniam videbo'", 1424 (España).
>
> ---
>
> *& si non se te suelve la postema con esto & vieres que ayunta venino, ayudal a mudar con las cosas que maduran & desi abrela con fierro.*
>
> Anónimo, "Tratado de patología", a1500 (España).

Nótese el uso del verbo *solver* en este último ejemplo como "deshacer" o "disolver", significado que también tenía el verbo *resolver* por entonces (y mantiene en su [acepción 7](https://dle.rae.es/?id=WBV06OC), aunque poco usada). Mismo significado que en el siguiente ejemplo, más antiguo, que ilustra además su uso en subjuntivo:

> *E sobr'esto pon tú que toda cabeça de río cualquier que sea que por elada o nieve que se suelva da mucha agua que non incha nin crece si non desque entra el verano, ca estonces se comiençan a delizar las nieves e los yelos que el poder del frío tiene elados.*
>
> Alfonso X, "General Estoria. Primera parte", c1275 (España).